# How to store Dimensions in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a unit conversion app written in SwiftUI. How do I store Dimensions and make them persist when the app is closed.
`@State var inUnit: Dimension = UnitMass.kilograms` I have searched around and can't find anything on storing or converting this to a string. All I need to store is the `UnitMass.kilograms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dimension` and its associated subclasses don't conform to `Codable`, so if you want to store them you have to rely on `NSSecureCoding`, which is not too hard:

```swift
let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
    withRootObject: UnitMass.kilograms, 
    requiringSecureCoding: true
)
```

Then on the other side:

```swift
let unarchived = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
    ofClass: UnitMass.self, 
    from: data
)
```

You can store and retrieve the `Data` from user defaults.